# Is there a software that allows replaying pre-saved fader positions?

Tags: software, mixer, asio, script, fader

I'm designing an upgrade to an existing sound system, with the goal of simplicity for the operator. I've got a strong computer background, and a modest (mainly car) audio background.

I've done some research and see that [digital mixers like this one](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/Ui24R--soundcraft-ui24r-remote-controlled-digital-mixer) use ASIO drivers to allow Windows software to interface w/ their hardware. Ideally, I'd like to just have a interface where the operator can press a button and the pre-saved fader levels are replayed onto the hardware.

I've looked at software like [Voicemeeter](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/) and see that it has some basic macro scripting capability, but haven't found solid documentation describing all of the capabilities of macro. Are there any options in this space for these features?

Answer (score 2):

All digital mixers have scene storage, usually of 100 or more scenes. Most of them will also have about 10 or more user assignable buttons(excluding most rack mounted) that you can set to recall a specific scene which would include the fader position or any other parameter that you want to store and can be recalled with a button.

Comment: In particular, part 8 of the user guide https://www.soundcraft.com/en/product_documents/ui24r_manual_v1-0_web-pdf mentions "A SHOW is a collection of SNAPSHOTS. A SNAPSHOT is a record of every setting on the console.
You can save and recall snapshots and shows via the Ui control software - Phone or Tablet."